# Cannot access product list pages "You can't access this account"

Tags: permission-sets, b2b-commerce

I'm using a user that belongs to a Buyer account and went to the site using the Log In to Experience as User but I always get an error when trying to access product pages...the rest of the pages work fine but not these ones.

It's confusing reading the error "You can't access this account" on those pages...I've permission sets assigned to that user to allow access but can't figure it out how to navigate to a product.

Here's the error:

[image]

Comment: Do we have any other components or any Account fields on that page? if yes, Can you check the user has that account access?

Comment: @NaveenBayya it's the Results Layout component but you can still see the filters and the sort options, which belong to the same component. The weird thing is that, after a while, I can start navigating through each category fine. This store includes buyer groups which are assigned to Entitlement Policies and all products have been assigned to this policy. I also can't add products to the cart somehow.

Comment: Can you try these steps: 1. From the B2B Commerce permission sets page, scroll down to Systems, and click System Permissions 2. Click Edit and select B2B Commerce User and Run Flows. Make sure 'commerce user' checkbox is checked.

Comment: Thanks @Swetha. That worked :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'll post this as an answer so it might help others too

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comments section,try these steps

1. From the B2B Commerce permission sets page, scroll down to Systems and click System Permissions
2. Click Edit and select B2B Commerce User and Run Flows. Make sure the 'commerce user' checkbox is checked.